# python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error in Scrapy (version 1.0.4)

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, scrapy

I'm working on a data scraping project and my code uses **Scrapy** (version **1.0.4**) and **Selenium** (version **2.47.1**).

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from selenium import webdriver

class TradesySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tradesy'
    start_urls = ['My Start url',]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
           tradesy_urls = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="right-panel"]"]')
           data_urls = tradesy_urls.xpath('div[@class="item streamline"]/a/@href').extract()
           for link in data_urls:
               url = 'My base url'+link
               yield Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_data)
               time.sleep(10)
           try:
               data_path = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-next"]')
           except:
               break
           data_path.click()
           time.sleep(10)

    def parse_data(self,response):
        'Scrapy Operations...'
```

When I execute my code, I'm getting expected output for some urls but for others I'm getting the following error.

```
2016-01-19 15:45:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET MY_URL> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
```

Please provide a solution for this query.

Answer (score 13):

according to this [reported issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1429) you could create your own `ContextFactory` to handle SSL.

**context.py:**

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory import ScrapyClientContextFactory


class CustomContextFactory(ScrapyClientContextFactory):
    """
    Custom context factory that allows SSL negotiation.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # Use SSLv23_METHOD so we can use protocol negotiation
        self.method = SSL.SSLv23_METHOD
```

**settings.py**

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY = 'yourproject.context.CustomContextFactory'
```

Comment: This solved my issue! (Readers take note that, of course, you need to change the 'yourproject' part in the pasted lined from above). Thanks, eLRuLL!!

Comment: Happy to help @Chris . Wineartist please remember to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: It worked too for `pyOpenSSL==17.5.0` & `Scrapy==1.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

Using Scrapy 1.5.0 I was running into this error:

```
Error downloading: https://my.website.com>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls12_check_peer_sigalg', 'wrong curve')]>]
```

What ended up working was updating my version of Twisted (from 17.9.0 -> 19.10.0). I also updated Scrapy to 2.4.0, and a few others:

- cryptography==2.2.2 -> 2.3
- parsel==1.4.0 -> 1.5.0
- pyOpenSSL==17.5.0 -> 19.0.0
- urllib3==1.22 -> 1.24.3

Answer (score 1):

Update as of **7/27/2022**

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1429#issuecomment-443396519). You could set the `DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD` to a value of `TLSv1.2` in the `settings.py` module. Other [versions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std-setting-DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD) can be tried as well, just try to tweak which would work.

> Just set the DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD property to 'TLSv1.2' in the
> settings.py of your project. There is no more need for you to use the
> custom context factory to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on eLRuLL's answer that does not require additional files. It 'decorates' the init method of the ScrapyClientContextFactory class.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory import ScrapyClientContextFactory

init = ScrapyClientContextFactory.__init__ 
def init2(self, *args, **kwargs):
  init(self, *args, **kwargs)
  self.method = SSL.SSLv23_METHOD
ScrapyClientContextFactory.__init__ = init2
```